# Connection between 'proxy', 'pronumeral' and 'pronoun'?

Tags: etymology, prefixes

I was thinking about the words *pronumeral* and *pronoun*; I realized they both share a prefix, and are both proxies for numerals and nouns. I was wondering if there is any connection between the words since *proxy* also begins with *pro*. If *proxy* is unrelated, is there any reason for the two words to start with *pro*?

Comment: What did the dictionary say?

Comment: I've never heard the word 'pronumeral' before. It seems to mean 'variable' in mathematics. Where have you used the word before?

Comment: @Mitch I'm a mathematician and a programmer, so I use the word all the time.

Comment: @annonymously: does it mean anything -different- from variable? Is it a variable of type integer?

Comment: A pronumeral is any letter that replaces a number (or other object like a vector), that is used to generalise a formula or equation, so that it can be valid using any appropriate object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, one of the senses of the prefix *pro-* is:

> Prefixed to nouns to form nouns and occas. derived adjectives with sense ‘deputizing for, standing in place of’.

This is the case of *pronoun* and *pronumeral*. The etymology for this particular sense is:

> in these, Latin prō- in the sense ‘for’, ‘instead of’, ‘in place of’, was prefixed to a noun, apparently originally in prepositional construction, as *prō consule* (one acting) for a consul, afterwards combined with the noun, as *prōconsul proconsul* n.1; so *prōflāmen* deputy flamen (compare flamen n.), *prōmagister* deputy head (compare magister n.), *prōpraetor* propraetor n.; also in a few names of things, as *prōnōmen* pronoun n., *prōtūtēla* deputy-guardianship (compare tutelage n.).

Now, what about *proxy*? The OED says that it was originally a form of *procuracy*, which is

> the office, action, or capacity of a procurator (procurator n.1 1); management or representation on behalf of another.

The etymology ties this to the Latin *prōcūrātio*. [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=procure&allowed_in_frame=0) provides some context into this, citing:

> c.1300, "bring about, cause, effect," from O.Fr. procurer (13c.), from L.L. procurare "to take for, take care of," in classical Latin, "manage, take care of;" from pro- "in behalf of" (see pro-) + curare "care for" (see cure).

So, *proxy*, *pronoun* and *pronumeral* do all share the same prefix *pro-*, although *proxy* came about its pronoun through *procuracy*.

Comment: `s/share the same pronoun/share the same prefix/`

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, edited. Too many "pro-s"

Comment: Still too many "pro-s"!  s/profix/prefix/